# WCF with IsolatedStoreFile

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service (Service1) where is some collection that I  need to store in an isolated area. So I try like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User |IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
    public static List<object> cutomerList = new List<Customer>();

    Service1()
    {
        if (!isoStore.FileExists("appData"))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("appData", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(isoStream, cutomerList);

            }
        }

    }
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomer()
    {

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("appData", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {

                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                List<Customer> obj2 = (List<Customer>)formatter.Deserialize(isoStream);

                return obj2;
            }
       }
```

But the file that I create exists only while application is ON. The same code in single ConsoleApplication works fine.

Any ideas?